# How can I create an affiliate program in WordPress?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

Suggestions for plugins, best practices, etc. welcome.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Not really; I don't have an existing project in mind, just looking to gather resources and ideas.

Comment: As in, do you mean you want to pay affiliates who bring customer signups to a premium area of your site? Your short question here is too vague for me and others here and the answers could go all over the place unless you help us.

Comment: Volomike, I understand.  Like I said, I don't have a specific use case in mind, and was more looking for resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just saw this article the other day:

http://pluginize.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-affiliate-program-in-wordpress/

They provide a tutorial and suggest using the following plugins:

- [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com)
- [WP Hide Dashboard](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-hide-dashboard/)
- [Gravity Forms Affiliate Add-On Plugin](http://www.gravityforms.com/category/gravity-forms-add-ons/)

The tutorial also has some code snippets that you will need to add. I haven't tried it out, but it would be great if you came back and posted your results, as I'm sure many people would find it useful. There are also a number of commercial products solely for this purpose; just google "[affiliate platform Wordpress](http://www.google.com/search?q=affiliate+platform+Wordpress)".